# Is MongoDB 2.x write concern { w : 1 } truly equals to { safe : true }?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

The title says it all, really. I can't seem to find a proper answer in doc for 'safe' keyword anymore, but w:1 = wait for standalone server (can be primary server in replicaSet env), which appears to fit my understanding of 'safe'.

Furthermore, we enable journaling on mongodb, is {j:true} required to make it compatible to {safe:true} ?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#write-concern

Comment: basically, yes. for the second one, if `{j: true}`, `{w: 1}` by default. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#internal-operation-of-write-concern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the documentation is never very good at telling yyou this stuff however, yes, `safe` is `w` 1. There are numerous sources out there but here is one for the PHP driver I find useful:

http://derickrethans.nl/mongoclient.html

Whereby he states:

> All of the other MongoDB drivers are making a similar change.

And:

> The biggest reason is that the new class will have acknowledged writes on by default—or expressed in deprecated wording: MongoClient has safe mode on by default.

So yes is the answer.

As for Journalling:

> we enable journaling on mongodb, is {j:true} required to make it compatible to {safe:true} ?

No a journal acked write is different to journaling in general. MongoDB will still continue to use the journal even if you use `w` 1 but it will not wait for a journal write before responding to your request. `j` is normally false by default.

Comment: Do you happen to know if 'safe' keyword is supported by the MongoClient class in newer drivers?

Comment: @bitinn Not in PHP, you will need to some kind of function to judge the verison. The easiest, that is compatible between all langguages, is to check for the existance of `MongoClient` and decide how to query from that, if you can garuantee that your app will use a driver with MongoClient then don't bother with this